# SharePoint Designer encountered an error during setup

Tags: sharepoint-designer, installation

I'm trying to install SharePoint Designer 2010, 32bit. The installation gets all the way to the end and then says

> "Microsoft SharePointDesigner encountered an error during setup. The
>   file {901....1CE}C\OfficeMUI.msi could not be found".

The workstation is `64bit Windows 7 Professional`, with Office 2010 32bit.

Other places [give conflicting information](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-ZA/sharepoint2010setup/thread/13838ec3-4ff0-4d28-a311-30a8c53bf9eb) as to whether 32 or 64 bit designer should be used when connecting to SharePoint 2010.

Comment: Connecting to SharePoint is irrelevant, the choice of which to install (32 or 64 bit) relies on what edition of Office you have (32 or 64 bit), it has to match.

Comment: @JamesLove, that thinking is why I attempted to install 32bit Designer. In any case I've since tried to install 64bit anyway and it refuses to because Office doesn't match, appropriately enough.

Comment: In my desktop where am having Win 7 Enterprise, SP 2010, Office 2013 professional plus-64 bit , so i installed SP 2010 Designer 2010 64-bit, faced some issues when I installed 32 bit of SP D 2010. so if possible, you can convert the office from 32 bit to 64 bit and install 63 bit SP  D 2010

Answer (score 0):

Have you attempted a repair installation of Office 2010? Sounds like one of it's support files is corrupt.

Comment: *sigh*, yes, running repair on Office itself yields the same error. Argh.

Comment: opened on SuperUser: http://superuser.com/questions/483135/repair-of-office-professional-did-not-complete-successfully

Answer (score 0):

Are here any components installed on your machine from other (older) office versions?

i.e. for the access data grid view to work in a list, the 32 bit access 2007 data access components need to be installed. if that is the case, remove  those components, install SPD and reinstall the access dao components

Comment: Thanks the tips. I no longer have the same machine or environment to follow through on troubleshooting, so can't answer. Maybe it will help someone else though.